# Is there a way to calculate metrics for different time periods in Quiver?

Tags: palantir-foundry

We have monthly data for a particular metric. Just wondering if it was possible to aggregate the data for different time periods in Quiver, eg. Year-to-Date, Moving Quarterly Total, Moving Annual Total etc.

The time series chart does have a rolling aggregate function but it does not support data that is segmented. It also only had display options for a line and a scatter plot, not a bar chart.

Comment: Is it possible for you expand the question with some table or code examples please? perhaps your table structure and/or screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute aggregations on variable time periods using a combination of [transform tables](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/timeseries-transform/#transform-time-series-in-batch) and [time series operations](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-transform-table-index-timeseries-operations/).

Use [time ranges](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-parameters/#time-range-parameter) to define the periods for which you want to aggregate on. Use the ranges as input to a [time series range filter](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-transform-table-index-timeseries-operations/#filter-to-time-range) to filter the time series data to different periods before applying the time series aggregation.

[Time operations](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-transform-table-index-time-operations/#time-operations) include a set of transforms that return a time range, such as [year to date](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-transform-table-index-time-operations/#year-to-date) and [month to date](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-transform-table-index-time-operations/#month-to-date).